# Why can't Benzoyl Peroxide kill fungi, unlike bactericidal and fungicidal Salicyclic Acid?

Tags: benzoyl-peroxide

> [**Benzoyl peroxide is not an anti-fungal.**](https://brookesbeautybazaar.com/which-is-better-benzoyl-peroxide-or-salicylic-acid-to-treat-fungal-acne-malassezia-folliculitis)

Why's Benzoyl Peroxide merely antibacterial, but NOT antifungal? Salicyclic Acid is both antibacterial<sup>1</sup> and antifungal<sup>2</sup>.

<sup>1</sup> [Song, Xiaoqiu, Rui Li, Qian Zhang, Shoukui He, and Yifei Wang. 2022. "Antibacterial Effect and Possible Mechanism of Salicylic Acid Microcapsules against *Escherichia coli* and *Staphylococcus aureus*" *International Journal of Environmental Research and Public Health* 19, no. 19: 12761. https://doi.org/10.3390/ijerph191912761](https://doi.org/10.3390/ijerph191912761)

<sup>2</sup> [Bénigne-Ernest Amborabé, Pierrette Fleurat-Lessard, Jean-François Chollet, Gabriel Roblin,
*Antifungal effects of salicylic acid and other benzoic acid derivatives towards Eutypa lata: structure–activity relationship,
Plant Physiology and Biochemistry*,
Volume 40, Issue 12,
2002,
Pages 1051-1060,
ISSN 0981-9428, https://doi.org/10.1016/S0981-9428(02)01470-5.](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0981942802014705)

Comment: Is there some reason you think it should be?

Answer (score 2):

That website is wrong! Many papers proving that Benzoyl Peroxide IS an anti fungal:

- [MIC for 5 yeasts](https://doi.org/10.1111/1346-8138.15739),
- [MIC for 3 yeasts](https://doi.org/10.1111/j.1365-2133.2005.06924.x).

That website ought to have written that benzoyl peroxide can't kill yeast ***associated with acne***.

Either way, differences in cell structure explain the different abilities of an antimicrobial compound being effective against some, but not other, microbes Some antimicrobials target the

- the replicative machinery of eukaryotes specifically,
- peptidoglycan synthesis in bacteria,
- chitin synthesis in yeast,
- lipids, which make gram positive bacteria and some yeast resistant to it.

The acne-causing yeast have some morphological difference which makes them impervious to benzoyl peroxide. I would venture that some sort of difference in the cell wall structure protects this yeast from benzoyl peroxide?